# How can I locale-format a python Decimal have a fixed number of decimals with trailing zeros

Tags: decimal, locale, python-3.10, trailing

I'm using Python 3.10.x

So I would like to have all my numbers/floats the same amount of decimals and make it a locale format with or a dot or a comma as separator (I would like to have users choose their own locale).

Let's say I have this number:

1.139682

I would like to have it localized, with 3 decimals and! with trailing zero if needed.

Oh yes, code!

```
def dutch_floats(price:float = None, my_locale:str="nl_NL")->str:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, my_locale)
    return (f"€ {price:n}")
```

so `print(dutch_floats(price=1.139682, my_locale="nl_NL"))`

gives me

€ 1,14

But I would like to have
€ 1,140

As when I have a number like
1.1243532

Would give me
€ 1,124

I tried all kinds of combinations

```
# price = float(f"{price:.3f}")
# return (f"€ {price:n}")

# price = float(f"{price:n}")
# return (f"€ {price:.3f}")

# return (f"€ {price:.3n}")

and so on
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the function name is dutch_floats, but first only dutch people started using it and now all kind of earthlings use it. I guess I need to rename the function name yes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rubber duck helped (ask me).

And it's all good with this line of code

`return locale.format_string("€ %.3f", price, grouping=False)`

My script looks like this

```
    @staticmethod
    def dutch_floats(price:float = None, my_locale:str="nl_NL")->str:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, my_locale)
        if price is None or price == "":
            return ""

        return locale.format_string("€ %.3f", price, grouping=False)
```